# How to navigate to next tab when submitting first form (tab) in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I am having a list of roles (in array) and displaying the list as tabs (which contains dynamic no. of roles).

I want to navigate to next tab (i.e., next form) automatically after successfully completing the first form.

How can I do this?

```
$scope.array = ["Actor", "Singer", "Lyricist"];
```

So my array length is 3 and I will display only Actor, Singer and Lyricist as tabs.

```
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(1)}" ng-if="roleActor==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getActorInfo()">Actor</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(2)}" ng-if="roleDirector==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getDirectorInfo()">Director</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(3)}" ng-if="roleSinger==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getSingerInfo()">Singer</a></li> 
<li ng-class="{active:isSelected(4)}" ng-if="roleLyricist==true"class="myli"><a href ng-click="getLyricistInfo()">Lyricist</a></li>
```

How can I navigate to second tab when I submitted first form (tab) and gets success message.

```
<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if="actor &&  !director && !singer && !lyricist>
   <h4><b>Please enter your mandatory details</b></h4>
            <hr width="90%" style="border-color: black; margin-left: 10px;">

            <form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()" ng-submit="savePostProfile()" novalidate>
            /* My form here */
</form>
</div>


<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if=" director && !actor && !singer && !lyricist>
   <h4><b>Please enter your mandatory details</b></h4>
            <hr width="90%" style="border-color: black; margin-left: 10px;">

            <form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()" ng-submit="savePostProfile()" novalidate>
            /* My form here */
</form>
</div>

<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if=" singer && !actor && !director && !lyricist>
   <h4><b>Please enter your mandatory details</b></h4>
            <hr width="90%" style="border-color: black; margin-left: 10px;">

            <form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()" ng-submit="savePostProfile()" novalidate>
            /* My form here */
</form>
</div>

<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if="lyricist && !actor && !director && !singer >
   <h4><b>Please enter your mandatory details</b></h4>
            <hr width="90%" style="border-color: black; margin-left: 10px;">

            <form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()" ng-submit="savePostProfile()" novalidate>
            /* My form here */
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your array has only 3 roles whereas your html supports 4 roles. Are you trying to show only the tabs specified in your `$scope.array`?

Comment: yes. I tried like this but for me one tabs get navigated and pages not remains as first array.  http://jsfiddle.net/kbjwymbq/11/

Answer (score 0):

keep a variable which will store the current role from which you can show its form and upon the submit success of that form change the current role to the next role of which the form is to be filled.

```
   <div ng-if=" selectedRole === 'Director'"> 
        <form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()" ng-submit="savePostProfile()" novalidate>
                /* My form here */
        </form>
   </div>
```

use a check for Current role in the savePostProfile method like given below :

```
    $scope.roles = ["Actor", "Singer", "Lyricist"];
    $scope.selectedRole = $scope.roles[0];
    $scope.savePostProfile = function(){
        var index = $scope.roles.indexOf($scope.selectedRole);
        console.log(index);
        //add this after save success
        if(index<$scope.roles.length-1){
          $scope.selectedRole = $scope.roles[index+1];
          console.log( $scope.selectedRole);
        }
        else{
          $scope.selectedRole = $scope.roles[0];///will go back to actor form or add anything you want
        }
      };
```

check the plunkr provided for working solution , i have removed css classes of your code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Fe08q8HU77KF9x2sjybb?p=preview